# Smarty to_charset Modifier

Tags: utf-8, smarty

How to use `to_charset` Smarty modifier?

What is the **correct syntax** for the same?

I am doing something like this, but doesn't seems to be working:

`<%$mystring|to_charset:"UTF-8"%>`

Answer (score 1):

That's how it worked for me:

```
{$cmnt_rsrc|to_charset:"ISO-8859-1"}
```